# Canary Islands Visa Requirements

Tags: visas, canary-islands

I am a non EU Passport holder but a resident in the UK.

What are the visa requirements to visit Canary Islands as a tourist with my family?

Comment: What’s your nationality? See http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LONDRES/en/Consulado/Pages/CheckPassport.aspx

Comment: @Traveller I am on list that requires a visa. However, I hold a valid UK residence permit as my wife is British. Does below text from your link mean I don't need visa: 6. Under Directive 2004/38/EC and according to Real Decreto 240/2007, 16 February, family members of an EU/EEA national in possession of a valid UK Residence Card specifying its condition as a family member do not require a visa to enter Spain when travelling with the EU/EEA National or joining him/her in Spain. Otherwise, a visa will be still required (Real Decreto 1161/2009, 10th July 2009). For spouses and/or children of Span

Comment: To clarify - Omani citizenship? Putting on hold as you didn't reply last time, but happy to reopen if clarified.